# EntityManager merge() hangs

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When I try to merge multiple entities, via multiple calls, my service seems to hang the 2nd time around when trying to merge back to back, however works fine if I only I only call this one with either entities, e.g. `service.updateFoo(foo1);` or `service.updateFoo(foo2);`

Here is what I have tried

Service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

@Service
public class FooService {

  private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
  private final FooRepository fooRepository;

  @Autowired
  public FooService(
      EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, FooRepository fooRepository) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
  }
  
  public Foo updateFoo(Foo foo) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    entityTransaction.begin();
    try {
      foo = entityManager.merge(foo); // hangs here the 2nd time
    } finally {
      entityManager.flush();
      entityTransaction.commit();
      entityManager.clear();
    }

    return foo;
  } 
}
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
}
```

Entity

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @NonNull private String userId;
  @Embedded private FooCaller fooCaller;

  @NonNull
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private FooStatus status;
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why do you need to create an EntityManager to merge your entity? Does not your `FooRepository` have a `save` method for that??

Comment: @CarlitosWay I have to write a query if I go the route with the FooRepository since some of my other fields (omitted) either need to be casted or have something else done with them and I am lazy

Comment: Also the other reason is so that I can get the actual updated entity back in one call.

Comment: Switching over to using the fooRepository works, but I am still curious on why the other way hangs...